# What does the number outside an array printed with print_r mean?

Tags: php

Given the following code:

```
<?php
$array = [1,2,3,[4,34]];
echo print_r($array);
 ?>
```

It results in the following output in the browser:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 34 ) ) 1
```

What does the 1 outside the array, at the end of the output attempting to display? Tried searching the PHP docs, but apparently no such number appeared at the end of their example.

Comment: it's because of the echo; remove it and it will disappear.

Comment: RTM on https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php  *"If you would like to capture the output of print_r(), use the **return** parameter. When this parameter is set to TRUE, print_r() will return the information rather than print it."*

Comment: the same for var_dump()  & var_export()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `1` you see is the **[truthy](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)** value of the **[`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)** function.

Because `print_r()` is a function in itself, it evaluates to truthy.

In your example, `print_r()` runs and outputs your array, followed by `echo`, which echoes out the truthy value of `print_r()`.

To eliminate this erroneous `1`, simply remove the `echo` from your code (which isn't needed, as `print_r()` outputs to the DOM by itself):

```
<?php
$array = [1,2,3,[4,34]];
print_r($array);
?>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: isn't means the print_r equals to true? because when you var_dump print_r it returns true.

Comment: `1` and `true` are both considered "truthy" - they both have positive connotations :)

Comment: Yeah, before your edit it wasn't clear!

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear -- hopefully the edit makes it a bit clearer now :)